# Java - Can't find constructor?

Tags: java

When trying to compile, my code can't compile:

```
package ch02.genericStringLogs;

public class DemoGenericLogs {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    GenericLogInterface<Float> genFloatLog = new LinkedGenericLog<Float>();
    LLGenericNode<Float> node0 = new LLGenericNode<Float>(2.2);
    LLGenericNode<Float> node1 = new LLGenericNode<Float>(3.3);
    LLGenericNode<Float> node2 = new LLGenericNode<Float>(4.4);
    LLGenericNode<Float> node3 = new LLGenericNode<Float>(5.5);
    genFloatLog.insert(node0);
    genFloatLog.insert(node1);
    genFloatLog.insert(node2);
    genFloatLog.insert(node3);

    System.out.println(genFloatLog.size());
    System.out.println(genFloatLog.toString());
    genFloatLog.clear();
    System.out.println(genFloatLog.size());

    GenericLogInterface<String> genStringLog = new LinkedGenericLog<String>();
    LLGenericNode<String> string0 = new LLGenericNode<String>("one");
    LLGenericNode<String> string1 = new LLGenericNode<String>("two");
    LLGenericNode<String> string2 = new LLGenericNode<String>("three");
    LLGenericNode<String> string3 = new LLGenericNode<String>("four");

    System.out.println(genStringLog.size());
    System.out.println(genStringLog.toString());
    genStringLog.clear();
    System.out.println(genStringLog.size());
  }
}
```

I get this error:

```
Error:
    part1/ch02/genericStringLogs/DemoGenericLogs.java:5: cannot find symbol
    symbol  : constructor LinkedGenericLog()
    location: class ch02.genericStringLogs.LinkedGenericLog<java.lang.Float>
```

Comment: As it says: Can't find a no argument constructor for the `LinkedGenericLog` class... And since you don't show that class, it is difficult to say much more...

Comment: Is your `LinkedGenericLog` class there in the same package?

Comment: yes it is. it is the same files as the ones listed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15122613/java-compile-time-error-compiler-not-recognizing-method-override

Comment: Why are you posting as a different user?

Comment: not a different user. somebody from my same class must've posted it as well

Answer (score 3):

Assuming it's the same class as the one in your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15122613/java-compile-time-error-compiler-not-recognizing-method-override/15122657#15122657), the only constructor for `LinkedGenericLog<T>` is this one:

```
public LinkedGenericLog(String name)
```

So when you construct one, you need to pass in a name. For example:

```
GenericLogInterface<Float> genFloatLog = new LinkedGenericLog<Float>("Some name");
```

If you don't want to have to pass in a name, you'll need to change `LinkedGenericLog` - add a parameterless constructor. What name do you want the log to have in that case though?

Comment: ok i have named it LinkedGenericLog<Float>("node")
but now i get an error on the following line
java:6: cannot find symbol
symbol  : constructor LLGenericNode(double)
location: class ch02.genericStringLogs.LLGenericNode<java.lang.Float>

Comment: The same thing. You need a constructor for LLGenericNode that takes a double as parameter.

Comment: @user1696035: You're passing it: 2.2. That should be 2.2f to be a `Float` rather than `Double`.

Answer (score 1):

This line...

```
GenericLogInterface<String> genStringLog = new LinkedGenericLog<String>();
```

indicates that you are attempting to invoke a no-argument constructor.

Your `LinkedGenericLog` class must not have a no-argument constructor if you're getting that error.  Java [provides one by default](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html), unless you define other constructors that do take arguments.